# booting from usb on dell g15 fails with errors after filechecks

Tags: boot, usb, dell

Today I tryied booting newest elementary os from usb, I tryied with 2 different usb sticks
same errors on both about unable to enumerate usb device

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good afternoon, I have the same problem, I can't install it on RedmiBook 14 Pro Ryzen Edition 2022 (Ryzen 7 6800H). When installing it gives an error: 2553.004479 ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110)